# Parallel line styles in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to draw advanced LineStyle's using MatPlotLib, specifically where a single plotted line with have a LineStyle such that there are parallel lines. Below is an artists rendition. Ideally, the parallel linestyle would be equidistant throughout the plot (in the example, it gets a little tight around corners)

[image]

Note: It looks like path_effects is close but that appears to do a static x,y offset relative to the line. the offset should be relative to the direction of the line.

EDIT: I'm looking something closer to the following, where a scatterplot essentially has the directionality built into the linestyle. See the attached where the the dashed line is always on the "right side" (or starboard) side of the trajectory.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)

v = []
X = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0.5])
Z = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0.5])

ax.plot(X, Z, 'r')


offset = 0.01
X = np.array([0, 1 - offset, 1 - offset, 0 + offset*2, 0.5 + offset*2])
Z = np.array([1 - offset, 1 - offset, 0 + offset, 0 + offset, 0.5])
ax.plot(X, Z, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

For reference, the type of lines I will be plotting will look like the example below (with with double lines), so simply plotting the line twice with a simple x or y offset will not do the trick.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is such a linestyle.  Your best bet is to calculate the parallel line yourself, and plot it separately.  If you are worried about finite difference effects, maybe re-sample at much higher resolution in data space first...

Comment: thanks Jody. I think that might be what i have to end up doing (and that's what i did manually in my edit above). that way will be a little clunky since it will be subject to zooming affects unless I really dig in and adjust the plot based upon events

Comment: Matplotlib has discussed brush styles a few times, but no one has ever implemented to my knowledge.

Comment: good to know. it'll be easy enough to create my own. it'll use the .line api so it'll certainly miss some edge cases

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ScaledTranslation` to create an offset transform, then apply the offset transform to the original transform. The example code is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import ScaledTranslation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
Y = 0.5*X - 1
Z = np.cos(X)

ax.plot(X, Y, 'b')
ax.plot(X, Z, 'r')


points= 1 / 72
dx, dy = 0, -10*points
offset = ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
ax.plot(X, Y, 'b--', transform=ax.transData + offset)
ax.plot(X, Z, 'r--', transform=ax.transData + offset)
```

For example, `ax.plot(X, Y, 'b--', transform=ax.transData + offset)` means to first plot the line in the data coordinates (`ax.transData`) and then shifted by `dx` and `dy` points using `fig.dpi_scale_trans`.

The obtained figure:

[image]

Comment: this is interesting but not quite what i'm looking for. this is very similear to what `path_effects` does, which his an x-y offset. I'll try to make a better visual aid in my comments above

Comment: I added a better visual aid in my comments above. the offset needs to be relative to the line direction, not relative to the X and Y axes